# Strapi Admin infinite loop

Tags: file-permissions, strapi

I'm kinda new to strapi. actually this the first time to try it. so i followed the documentation and was able to get the first page to work but admin page always go blank. sadly i don't know nodeJs or react so I'm not sure about what to do in here but seems there's something wrong with the permissions please check the attached image.

[image]

i've tried

```
npm install in the project root directory.
npm run setup in the project root directory.
```

as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1892) on github but it want's useful

I'm using
strapi 3 alpha
nodeJs 11
npm 6+
mariaDB 10.1
windows 10 64bit

Comment: Hello! what are you trying to do to have this issue ?

Comment: i'm just trying to access the admin login page for the first time by hitting http://localhost:1337/admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simply, I checked strapi website to find out that version 3 is out of the alpha status and then I installed the newer version and tried to use it and it did work so seems some bug was in the alpha edition which strapi team has fixed by themselves

Comment: I have installed 3.0.0-alpha.25.2

Comment: alpha version ended and stable version is released just install another fresh copy it will have the issue fixed

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to clean the database your use. And when it's done, restart your Strapi server. It will re-create all table needed by Strapi.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after setting up SSL on Digital Ocean one-click. I just ran `npm run build`. I did not do anything with the database.